# Export / Import SSAS CUBE between local machine and server

Tags: ssas

I have a cube, which I built in my local machine. So will it work, if I export this cube by using SQL Server and import it in the another server or machine?
Because I have export and import but getting error when process.
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean backup/restore when you talk of export/import? You can access a restored cube that was backed up on another computer without problems. For processing, you probably need to adapt the data source settings of the restored cube, as the way you restored it, the data source will point to where it pointed to on your local machine, and this may not be from where you want to drag the data. Also, check the security settings (account with which to connect to the relational data source).

The easiest way to change all these settings is using Management Studio on the restored cube:

- Connect to the AS server in Management Studio.
- Open the database that you deployed in Object Explorer (each BIDS Analysis Services project results in a deployed database).
- Open the Data Source object, and edit as appropriate: Especially, the Connection String and Impersonation Info are relevant. If you click into these fields, a button appears in the right, which lets you open an editor. You can use any relational database that can be accessed by the Windows user you configure as the Impersonation info. The connection parameters are not specific to Analysis Services, but standard for the relational source that you are using. For Impersonation Info, it normally works well to use "Impersonate Service Account" if you are accessing a relational SQL Server database running on the same server, otherwise, you should use a specific Windows user name and password. In the latter case,chose a user for whom the password never expires, as otherwise, you will have tio change these settings as soon as the password changes.
- Leave the dialog with OK.

How exactly you have to configure the connection parameters, and which impersonation settings do or do not work depends on your individual setup. The DBA of your relational database should be able to help you for this, as this is standard stuff for connecting to the relational database.

And of course, the change of the data source should be compatible: the tables and views referenced in the data source view should be available in the new database, and the SQL you used for named columns should be in a SQL dialect understood by the new database.

Comment: Hi,
I make a cube which I will have to store in my client's server so that they work on that cube perfectly.
I think when I build the cube, the cube will contain some settings including server name. So how can I fix the settings or store the cube to my client server so that it work properly?
thnkx :)

Comment: @Tuhin I added a step by step description to my answer.

Comment: @Tuhin If the answer answers your question, you should mark it as the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left of the answer. Then it is shown as answered question in SO.

Comment: hi, If you please elaborate the answer in some specific ways? 
if I need to point the data source in my server machine or not? because, in that remote server we can't open/point/browse DB servers in Visual Studio.
since, I am unable to solve the problem from you answer so I can't mark it answer, otherwise people may miss understand!